# Can I use the same index in 2 different tables but on the same columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table and need to create its duplicate in Oracle (including indices and sequences) as a history of the first one. To create the table with its data I can do like this:

```
create table new_table as select * from original_table;
```

Of course, this will not create any index, sequence or trigger which the original table has. Creating all that I can do in few ways. My question is not how can I create all that but **my question is the following**:

- Since the newly created table is a copy of the original (columns are the same) can I use the same index which exists on the original table for the new one too?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "using the index". Can you create an index on `new_table` with the same name as the existing index? No. With the same columns as the existing index? Yes. Will the existing index on `original_table` help queries on `new_table`? No.

Comment: By using the same index I mean not to create a copy of an existing index (with the same name) on the original table for the new one but is there an opportunity to choose an existing index and set it as an index on the new table?

Comment: you need to recreate indexes for `new_table` for the queries to use them.

Comment: You could create an `index cluster` and then create more than 1 table  by adding common columns to that cluster. I am not sure if we could do this for existing tables.

Comment: You can't use the same index, but of course you could use the same sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index entry points to the location of a records data at a particular location in a block. The data in your history table cannot exist in the same location as the data in the original table so therefore the locations being pointed to will never match. If you research how an index actually works in Oracle you will see why this is not possible.